# [LAContext biometryType]: unrecognized selector on iOS 11.0.0

Tags: ios, swift

I see dozens of crashes in fabric

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
-[LAContext biometryType]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c066aa00
```

And it's strange because I do call biometryType on LAContext only for iOS 11+.

The code:

```
    private static var biometryType: BiometryType? {
        let context = LAContext()

        guard context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: nil),
            context.evaluatedPolicyDomainState == BiometryManager.savedPolicyDomainState else { return nil }

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            switch context.biometryType {
            case .typeFaceID: return .typeFaceID
            case .typeTouchID: return .typeTouchID
            case .none: return nil
            }
        }
        return .typeTouchID
    }
```

[image]

Any suggestions?

The only clue I have is that all crashes related to 11.0.0. So maybe Apple added biometryType not in 11.0.0 but a bit later.

Links:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype

http://www.codeprocedures.com/question/nsinvalidargumentexception-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-on-specific-phone-with-ios-11/

Comment: Which devices do generate this crash? Have you verified that it's devices capable of biometric data? I'm wondering wether that guard statement is not working as it should

Comment: It crashes on all kind devices except iPhone X but it's mostly iPhone 7.

Comment: Ok, obviously you are right about the guard statement. Is it working fine with iPhone 7 when you test it ?

Comment: @Lefteris yes, it woks on my iPhone 7 and even on iPhone X.

Comment: Is it possible that an error is occurring but you're not seeing it because you pass `nil` in for the error parameter in `LAContext.canEvaluatePolicy`?

Comment: @MatthewSeaman I guess if canEvaluatePolicy got an error It must return false and then guard will protect us from the rest of the function

Comment: We have a device still running iOS 11.0 beta and have this problem. 11.0 was released before Face ID was announced so it didn't have this method yet. Not sure whether it's what you see but that's what we encountered anyway.

Comment: @RyanFung yes, probably it's the same problem.

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in the iOS 11.0 simulator from Xcode 9.0? Or only on devices running iOS 11.0?

Comment: Any idea how to reproduce this? I am on a 6Plus running iOS 11.0(15A372) Xcode 9.2.
I am doing 
`if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {context.biometryType}` and it doesn't crash for me

Comment: @akshay1188 you need a device with iOS 11 *beta* to be able to reproduce that

Comment: @Arsen Okay. So only the beta version had the crash issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @stonesam92 said, it is probably a bug in ios 11.0.0. The below code safeguards me against the crash.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *), authenticationContext.responds(to: #selector(getter: LAContext.biometryType))
```

Comment: I did file a bug report with Apple. Awaiting their response :P

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in the iOS 11.0 simulator from Xcode 9.0? Or only on devices running iOS 11.0?

Comment: @AdamJohns when attempting to download "iOS 11.0 Simulator" from Xcode components, it would actually install iOS 11.0.1 where this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 11):

This works as well:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0.1, *) {...}
```

The iPhone X first release was on 11.0.1

From crash reporting, this definitely works.

Answer (score 3):

It's not much of a solution, but this appears to be a bug in iOS 11.0.

I've seen multiple reports of this crash and all have been resolved when the user upgraded to a more recent version of iOS.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for Objective-C(on iOS 11.0 & below versions)

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *) && [context    respondsToSelector:@selector(biometryType)])
            {}
```

credits to @Sonu VR